Extending the object type of a function argument
I want to extend the function argument type by adding a function with any name to each object and return it, but i am facing a problem with naming the key of the added function

export type Expand<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K]: T[K] extends { [K in string]: unknown }
    ? ExpandData<T[K]>
    : T[K] | ((p: T) => T);
};
type ExpandData<T extends { [K in string]: unknown }> = T | Expand<T>;

export const create = <T,>(params: Expand<T>): Expand<T> => {
  return params;
};


I want to use it like this, where the function change: (val) => val will return me the value of the object where it is located ( with any name instead of "change" )

type ICreate = {
  param: {
    first: {
      value: number;
    }
  }
}

const result = create<ICreate>({param: {
  first: {
    value: 1,
    change: (val)=> val, // type val = { value: number }
  }
}})

and get as a result type in the form
  {
    param: {
      first: {
        value: number
        change: Function 
      }
    }
  }

How to do this correctly?
( ICreate type may change, I'm looking for a generic solution )

I'm having a very hard time understanding what Expand and ExpandData is supposed to be. writing {[K in string]: unknown} means you care about index signatures, and writing {[K in ⋯ as K | string]: ⋯} means you're pretty much destroying all information about K (unless K is a number or a symbol). It's a weird recursive type and it's not obvious to me what its purpose is. What function are you talking about whose argument you want to augment? Please [edit] this to clarify what you're trying to do. Right now I'm mystified.

I understand that the current implementation of the type is incorrect, I left it as an example. I edited it, describing what type I want to get as a result

Assuming I understand (which might be wrong because you've only shown a single test case), it's not possible directly. "A function with any name" is not a specific type. Worse, there's no way to say "any name except for keyof XXX" (see ms/TS#17867) so you can't do this arbitrarily without messing up the existing properties as well.  You can possibly check against such a constraint, but it means you'd need a helper function as shown in this playground link and then TS won't want to infer val either.

(see prev comment). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer (although it's somewhat disappointing). If not, what am I missing?

Yes, I came to the option through a helper function, but I thought that it could be implemented somehow in this way. Thank you very much for the answer

It would be much better if you had a consistent property name for the "change" function, and not just "any name" which is bizarre anyway (how would you discover it?)  Would that be possible?

the original idea was to have a unique name so that you could add an unlimited number of functions, such as increment:(value) => value+ 1, decrement:(value) => value - 1, and then return those functions. to implement this you will have to use an additional function, but it will look less convenient

So you can still have an unlimited number of functions if you use an approach as shown in this playground link. Is it okay to use a known key like fns for an object of functions? This approach works so much better (see how val is inferred). If that works for you I'd be happy to write an answer showing this and why it's better. If not, why not?

I think this option is perfect, thank you

There really isn't a useful specific type that works this way. You'd like to say that you'll allow T to have any extra key not present in T, and the property at that key will be of type (val: T) => T. The stumbling block is that you can't say "any key except for keyof T".  That would require something like a "rest index signature" or a "default property type" as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#17867. But that isn't part of the language. There are various workarounds discussed at How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property.  You could certainly describe a generic constraint which validates objects like this, but it won't let you infer the parameter type of the functions you add. It's a mess to do it that way.
It would be much much better for you to add a single property with a known key (like fns) that contains values of type (val: T) => T... pushing those functions down one level.  That can be described as a specific type like this:
type Expand<T> =
  T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]: Expand<T[K]> } &
  { fns?: { [k: string]: (val: T) => T } } :
  T

It's a recursive conditional type that intersects each object type with an object optionally containing a fns property with an index signature.  For
type ICreate = {
  param: {
    first: {
      value: number;
    }
  }
}

the expanded version is equivalent to
type ExpandICreate = Expand<ICreate>;
/* type ExpandICreate = {
    param: {
        first: {
            value: number;
            fns?: { [k: string]: (val: { value: number }) => { value: number }}
        }
        fns?: { [k: string]: 
          (val: { first: { value: number }}) => { first: { value: number }}
        }
    }
    fns?: { [k: string]: (val: ICreate) => ICreate }
} */

That's enough to make your original version sort of work, but an index signature doesn't "remember" which keys are present, and optional properties don't "remember" if they are there or not:
const create = <T,>(params: Expand<T>) => params;

const result = create<ICreate>({
  param: {
    first: {
      value: 1,
      fns: {
        change: (val) => val,
      }
    }
  }
});

result.param.first.value.toFixed(); // okay
result.param.first.fns.change({ value: 1 }); // error, fns might be undefined
result.param.first.fns?.change({ value: 1 }); // okay
result.param.first.fns?.whaaaaa({ value: 1 }); // also okay

If you want TS to know that fns exists under first and that change exists under fns and that whaaaaaa does not exist under fns, then you need to make create() even more generic. You'd like to write
const create = <T, U extends Expand<T>>(params: U) => params;

but there's no way to call this where you manually specify T and have the compiler infer U. That would be microsoft/TypeScript#26242 and it isn't part of the language. The workaround here is currying:
const create = <T,>() => <U extends Expand<T>>(params: U) => params;

So you call create<ICreate>() and that returns a function you call with params:
const result = create<ICreate>()({
  param: {
    first: {
      value: 1,
      fns: {
        change: (val) => val,
      }
    }
  }
})

result.param.first.value.toFixed(); // okay
result.param.first.fns.change({ value: 1 }); // okay
result.param.first.fns.whaaaaa({ value: 1 }); // error

That now works how you'd like it.
Playground link to code
